# What is the right age for circumcision?

Tags: fiqh, circumcision, khitan

According to Islam what is the right age for circumcision and when can it be done?

Comment: It's recommended to get a male circumcised as early as possible. Take a look at http://www.circinfo.com/guide_to_decision/ages.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Male Circumcision is among the rites of Islam and is part of the (in Arabic): fitrah,

*As recorded in Hadith@*

> Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said, "Five are the acts quite akin to fitrah:Circumcision, clipping or shaving the pubes, cutting the nails, plucking  or shaving the hair under the armpits and clipping (or shaving) the moustache." (Reported in  Bukhari & Muslim)

*The Time for Circumcision@*

> During the time of the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) circumcision was done for boys at the time of their Aqiqah (It's a traditional celebration for the birth of a child which involves the sacrifice of an animal in thanks to Allah. That's the short answer) as reported in al-Bayhaq.

Other Hadiths mention it being done later. The details here are not important but it goes without saying that this minor operation is easier on a baby than it is on an older boy.

If it is essential, circumcision `can be delayed for practical reasons, but it would be sensible to perform circumcision before the boy starts praying`regularly due to practical purposes of simplifying Taharah, or being clean.

*Abdullah Ibn Jabir (r.a.) and Aisha (r.a.) said@*

> The Prophet (peace be upon him) performed the Aqiqah of al-Hasan and al-Hussein (the prophets grandsons) and circumcised them on the 7th. Day.

Thus, It would be good to circumcision within a few days after the birth of the child.

Some scholar also recommended that circumcision is  to be performed on the `seventh day of infancy-the day of  Aqiqah.`

*MAY ALLAH GUIDE US*

Comment: *it goes without saying that this minor operation is easier on a baby than it is on an older boy.* - Note: It's a myth that babies do not feel pain - [What parents need to know about pain in newborns](https://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/what-parents-need-to-know-about-pain-in-newborns-201601269076). So unless you want use anaesthesia or pain killers on a baby, which is dangerous, it is best to do it when the child is older but before puberty. That's what some muslim community in India do. And they also make it into a small festivity where the circumcised boy gets gifts from family & friends

Answer (score 2):

First look at this hadees

> **Narrated Abu Huraira: Allah's Apostle said, "Five practices are
>   characteristics of the Fitra: circumcision, shaving the pubic region,
>   clipping the nails and cutting the moustaches short." (Bukhari Book
>   72, Hadith 777)**

So you should ask your self...

**"How fast you want your child to have characteristics of the Islamic Fitra?"?**

*As a muslim, it should be the earliest. We should race towards good deeds...*

Another thing I have heard is that if circumcision is done late, the child feels mutilated if they don't understand the reasoning behind doing it. So many recommend as early as possible.

A small note about antibiotics.... Allah forbid your child is playing and hurts himself, he might have to take much more heavy dose of antibiotics than the ones required for this small procedure.

Comment: dear friend,I practice natural healing for my family and my son.so by grace of Allah we have been living without Allopathic medicine for few years and my son havent used it till now.Alhamdullilah we are Happy.And for me taking a small quantity of antibiotics is also similar to haram since it brings problems destroys the body.jazakallah khair

Comment: not using allopathy is a personal choice, but natural medicines too may have some anti biotics etc. look for alternatives in ayurveda or naturopathy. If nothing is available, i'd recommend following command of Allah and His Messenger(pbuh) rather than medication methods. If you do it for Allah.... Allah will remove all the harm Insha Allah.

Answer (score 0):

Circumcision is obligatory according to the Shafi'is and Hanbalis and according to them the time at which it becomes obligatory is after puberty - however it is recommended to do it in infancy or young age as at that time it is easier and heals better. The following are the various stances on the recommended time:

- 7 days of age
- 7-10 years of age
- the age when milk teeth fall out
- there is no set time rather it is left to the discretion of the people

There is a hadith on 7 days, although it is weak. 7-10 years is based on analogy with the time when parents are to tell their children to start performing prayers. And the last stance is based on the fact that there is no proper evidence which defines the time and so there is no fixed time.

**Ref:** [Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah 19/28](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/11355)