# What is supposed to be given in the aqeeqah of a baby boy or a baby girl? Is it the same if not given on the 7th day of birth?

Tags: sharia, aqeeqah

My sister gave birth to a baby boy last year in March. We couldn't perform his Aqeeqah due to his illness. [This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1874/what-is-the-right-age-for-circumcision/1890#1890) answer says that the Aqeeqah has to be given on the 7th day.

*Questions:*

- What is supposed to be given in the Aqeeqah of a baby boy or a baby girl?
- What should be given in the Aqeeqah if we couldn't do it on the 7th day?

Comment: I don't think Aqeeqah is mandatory. You can skip it if you want to

Comment: I changed the second question to ask what shall be given after the 7th day. If it's not what you meant then please change it back and clarify the question.

Answer (score 2):

**What is supposed to be given in the Aqeeqah of a baby boy or a baby girl?**

It is prescribed to slaughter two sheep for a newborn boy and one sheep for a girl, as is indicated by the saheeh evidence, such as the following:

> It was narrated from ‘Aa’ishah (may Allaah be pleased with her) that
>   the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)
>   commanded them (to slaughter) two sheep of similar type for a boy and
>   one sheep for a girl.

Narrated by al-Tirmidhi, 1513, who said it is hasan saheeh; classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi.

**What should be given in the Aqeeqah if we couldn't do it on the 7th day?**

The best time for offering the ‘aqeeqah is seven days after the birth, because the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said:

> “Every child is held in pledge for his ‘aqeeqah, which should be
>   slaughtered on his behalf on the seventh day, and he should be shaved
>   and given his name.”

Narrated by Abu Dawood, 2838; classed as saheeh by Shaykh al-Albaani in Saheeh Abi Dawood.

If it is delayed until after the seventh day, then there is no problem and it may be offered when the Muslim is able to do that. Also, Aqeeqah is a (Sunnah Muakkadah) confirmed Sunnah not an obligation.
And Allah knows best.

Source: [Rulings regarding Aqiqa](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=83120), [Aqeeqah - Islamqa.info](http://islamqa.info/en/60252).

Answer (score 0):

```
             In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful
```

Although some scholars believe that it is mandatory to slaughter (sacrifice or aqeeqah) at the 7th day of the birthday[1], but **in accordance with the view of most scholars[2] , it Is Mustahab to slaughter(doing Aqeeqah) a sheep at the 7th day of baby’s birthday.** Of course seemingly they emphasized the significance of it anyway.

According to some traditions, **the best animal for the Aqeeqah is “Sheep”, then camel , then every animal which is possible to be sacrificed..**
**It is Sunnah that you do it even till end of your life ( in the case that you couldn’t do it at the 7th day), hence if you couldn’t give any Aqeeqah till 7th day, then do it whenever possible.**

**About the gender of the sheep (for the Aqeeqah), Imam Sadegh (a.s.) mentioned that if the newborn was boy, the sheep should be male, and if the newborn was girl, the sheep should be female.(Of course seemingly, it is not mandatory, but seems to be better if the gender…)**

> [1] Al-Entesar Fi Enferadat Al-Emamiah p:406  الانتصار في انفرادات
>   الإمامية، ص 406
>
> [2] Al-Helli, Al-Allamah, Hasan ibn Yusf ibn Motahar Al-asadi …
>
> الحلّي، العلّامة، حسن بن يوسف بن مطهر الاسدي‌،...

(To see the complete text of the mentioned reference, you can see the source.)

---

**Sources:**

http://islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa21644

http://www.farsnews.com/printable.php?nn=8904300331

Comment: Jashakallah! I want to ask two qestions. 
1) I heard about If the newborn was boy, we have to give only one sheep ( or other animal), if the new born was girl, the count of sheep should be two? Is this true? Or any hadis proof is der?
2) What is meant by Mustahab?

Comment: Mustahab means highly recommended sunnah. You will be rewarded for Mustahab actions but won't be blamed/punished for not doing them.

Comment: Yeah, u r right @fluuufffy. but to complete ur word I should say tht: as far as I know, there r 2 kinds of Mustahab, 1:Mustahab(recommended practice), 2: Mustahab-al-Muakad(highly recommended). then it depend upon if it is Mustahab or Mustahab-al-Muakad. Good luck.